# How do we view someone else's repo discussion on GitHub?

Tags: github

I have navigated from one closed issue that has migrated to ["Sluggish scrolling in notebook windows [monaco editor restore] #117644"](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/117644) because I am experiencing the same sluggish issues on a MBP. At the end of the thread there seems to be a work around, but no official answer.

I know there are discussions that can be enabled and may not be the best way to approach this particular problem, but I don't remember how to view someone else's discussion if it were enabled for a repo or a group of them.

Does anyone have a suggestion on the best way to handle finding an official answer or reaching out to someone that has made efforts to resolve an issue like one from a Microsoft repo?

Answer (score 0):

For VSCode navigate back to main Microsoft repo, click on vscode, and scroll to the bottom to find the [link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-discussions/discussions)